# Relationship between MIPS (Million Instructions per second) and operating frequency of a processor

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

Let's say there is an algorithm that runs on a processor at ***x MIPS***, operating at a clock frequency of ***y MHz***. If I double the operating frequency to ***2y***, what happens to the MIPS? It seems to me that doubling the operating frequency should double the instructions executed per second, i.e, MIPS = ***2x***, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Only if you double the speed of everything. Which you can’t in practice.

Comment: Since MIPS probably disregard memory or other I/O, I don't follow.

Comment: MIPS don't have a choice. If you read from or write to memory, it takes as long as it takes.

Comment: I was thinking of FLOPS which, afaik, are measured/calculated assuming no I/O happens. Which is purely theoretical, of course, but still.

Comment: This answer would be fine if it had some justification. As always, we're looking for answers that explain why they're right.